# Какие существуют численные методы для метода наименьших квадратов?

Tags: c++, matlab, статистика, численные-методы

У меня имеется следующий код в Matlab:

```
fileID = fopen('input.txt','r');
formatSpec = '%f';
y = fscanf(fileID,formatSpec);

step = 0.1;
x0 = step;
xn = length(y)*0.1;
x = x0:step:xn;

fitfunc = 'a + exp(x/b)+x^2/3+x'
startPoints = [-1 -1];

[f2 f2_info] = fit(x',y,fitfunc, 'Start', startPoints)
disp('Coefficients values: ');
coeffvalues(f2)
disp('Forecasts value on 600s: ');
f2(600)
```

Этот код выполняет фиттинг данных и строит прогноз на 600 секунду процесса.

Задача состоит в следующем: этот код нужно вшить в прибор, поэтому мне нужно преобразовать данный код в код на С++. Вижу несколько решений:

1. Поискать автоматические преобразователи кода MATLAB в код С++
2. Найти на С++ готовые библиотеки фиттинга, и используя их, переписать код.
3. Самому запрограммировать итерационный процесс фиттинга, для этого придется погрузиться в теорию.

1 вариант: попробовал использовать Matlab Coder, который автоматически конвертирует код в C. Но, к сожалению, Matlab Coder не поддерживает функцию fit.

2 вариант отпадает, т.к. использование сторонних библиотек требует много памяти, которой в приборе недостаточно для таких изысков.

Остается 3 вариант, но в теории плохо разбираюсь, залез в код Matlab, там очень сложный объектно-ориентированный язык (я смотрел исходный код функции fit) , у меня не хватает компетенции понять этого.

Затем я задал вопрос на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855594), где люди подсказали, что скорее всего используется метод наименьших квадратов (МНК).

Гуглил русскоязычный и англоязычный интернет, но там в основном аналитические решения, и то для полиномов. В аналитических решениях есть минус: если поменять функцию фиттинга, то нужно каждый раз пересчитывать производные и забивать в код. Поэтому мне нужны численные решения, чтобы можно было быстро тестировать интерполяцию разными функциями.

Затем, кажется, я нашел то, что мне нужно: Метод Левенберга-Марквардта. Прочитал статьи на википедии и на machinelearning.ru, но не могу понять, как это практически применить.

Может есть знающие люди, кто мог бы кратко описать алгоритм метода Левенберга-Марквардта для моей функции fitfunc = 'a + exp(x/b)+x^2/3+x' ? Либо посоветовать любой другой численный метод для поиска коэффициентов фиттирующей нелинейной функции.

Comment: Есть еще вариант, матлаб умеет заворачивать свой код в библиотеку, которую можно вызывать из C++. Вопрос в том смогут ли матлабовские dll-ки заработать на той платформе что вам нужна в итоге.

Comment: Строго говоря тут надо понять что вы хотите интерполяцию или аппроксимацию.  Разница в том как ведет себя функция в известных точках: интерполяция - проходит строго через них, при этом между точками ее может изогнуть волной. аппроксимация - проходит максимально близко к точкам но не обязательно через них.  Аппроксимация решается методом наименьших квадратов, для него требуется решить матрицу уравнений, которая достаточно неплохо реализуется методом ньютона с выбором главного элемента - задача на лабораторную

Comment: Андрей, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Андрей, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Андрей, спасибо за ответ. В данном случае мне необходима аппроксимация. По поводу метода Ньютона с выбором главного элемента - прогуглил, нашел метод Гаусса с выбором главного элемента, вы его имели ввиду?

Comment: Вы постановку задачи знаете, как собственно работает метод наименьших квадратов и откуда берется система уравнений?

Comment: Думаю, что да. Но правильно ли я понимаю, что если я поменяю функцию, то мне придется заново пересчитывать систему уравнений? То есть заново искать производные и выражать формулы для подсчета коэффициентов?

Comment: Если вдруг кому-то интересно, то я просто реализовал численный метод половинного деления для двух переменных с критерием суммы наименьших квадратов. Функцию можно спокойно менять как угодно, и не нужно высчитывать производные и системы уравнений. Если потребуется код, пишите, отправлю.

Comment: лучше указывайте сразу всё что может помочь другим людям, столкнувшимся с аналогичной проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

На всякий случай пишу постановку задачи и что откуда берется, на примере 2 мерного случая:

1. У вас есть данные измерений  Xi, Yi - точки снятые при калибровке и тому подобное.
2. У вас есть набор базисных функций Fn которыми вы хотите представить искомую зависимость, к набору функций предъявляется требование ортогональности. Самый простой набор это X^0, X^1, X^2,... или sin^n(X), cos^n(X)

Задача: Вы хотите подобрать такие коэффициенты C0, C1, ... Cn, чтобы функция Sum(Cn*Fn(Xi)) проходила максимально близко к Yi, для всех i.

Решение: 
Вы берете вашу систему и подставляете туда все известные Xi, из каждого полученного значения вычитаете Yi, возводите в квадрат, все складываете и минимизируете данную сумму.
{(Sum(Cn*Fn(X0)) - Y0) ^ 2 + (Sum(Cn*Fn(X1)) - Y1) ^ 2 ... (Sum(Cn*Fn(Xi)) - Yi) ^ 2} -> min

Для минимизации вам надо взять частные производные по Cn и приравнять их всех нулю, это даст вам систему из n уравнений, решив которую вы найдете искомые Cn.

Систему уравнений решаете любым способом, часто она бывает плохообусловлена, особенно при снятии данных с погрешностью, потому хорошо бы выбирать методы с этим справляющиеся. Метод Ньютона (Ньютона-Гауса) решения именно систем уравнений подходит. Метод решения с выбором главного элемента оказался просто методом Гауса, его тоже стоит попробовать, но он кажется хуже справляется с плохообусловленными системами. Вики говорит что выбранный вам изначально метод Левенберга-Марквардта является расширением метода Ньютона.

Comment: Функция что вы передаете в fit - это как раз ваш набор базисных функций, потому естественно вам придется пересчитать все Sum(Cn*Fn(Xi))

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, с помощью него я понял, чего я вообще хотел.

Comment: В итоге этот численный метод решает все-таки систему уравнений. Быть может вы знаете, есть ли какой-нибудь метод такого типа: увеличиваю один коэффициент, критерий R квадрат увеличился, значит иду в правильном направлении, уменьшаю коэффициент, критерий R квадрат уменьшился, разворачиваемся. И таким образом просто подобрать наилучшую комбинацию коэффициентов, существует ли такой численный метод?

Comment: Ну вы только что его описали:) В чем сложность: вы минимизируете функцию суммы квадратов отклонения. А эта функция не обязательно имеет один локальный минимум на интересующем отрезке. Грубо вы можете сделать шаг влево, увидеть что функция растет, пойти в право, найти минимум. Но вы не можете утверждать что пройдя влево 10 шагов вы не найдете минимум меньше того что вы нашли справа.

Comment: Есть методы итерационные, собственно вы делаете шаг в нужную сторону пока получаете уменьшение, как только перестали делаете шаг назад и пол шага в эту сторону, и так далее, пока не получите заданную точность. Но вопрос выбора начальной точки очень важен, он будет вас приводить в ближайший локальный минимум, и не факто что это будет абсолютный минимум функции. Можно искать минимумы от сетки значений, можно применять статистические методы, вариантов и методов реально много....

Comment: Спасибо большое за внесенную ясность, Андрей :) Жалко, что из-за моей сегодняшней регистрации пока что не могу поставить вам + в репутацию :(